# Doctrine One To Many No Join Table

Tags: php, doctrine

I am using Doctrine and I am wondering if I could have a One To Many relationship without the use of a join table ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A join table is only required for m:n relations.

Comment: Thanks meze.  I was just wondering since the documentation only shows a 1:m relationship with a join table.

Comment: What version? The [documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) for doctrine2 shows two examples with only two tables:

Comment: Here is the link I was looking at section 5.9 specifically. http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

Answer (score 6):

Depends on whether you want it to be unidirectional or bidirectional.

Unidirectional one-to-many can be made only through join table, for "ideological" reasons, which came from Java's hibernate:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table

Imagine you have a Category which has many Products, and you want a *unidirectional* relationship - i.e. category knows about many products, but products don't know about category.

If you put a 'category_id' field into Product table, you will make product table "aware" of the fact that it is connected to category. And you will not be able to remove this relationship without altering Product table - that means it is not truly unidirectional.

But if you keep relationship between category and products in the separate join table, you can just drop it and Product won't even notice that something has changed.